# Export Excel stylesheet to CSV with comma separated and cells with text format in double quotes

Tags: excel, csv, export

Example - Source:

```
ID  NAME   TEXT  
01  John   Lore ipsum..
```

In this case all cells have format General and Lore ipsum.. text have format Text

And I want export this excel stylesheet to csv with comma separated and lore ipsum.. text with double quotes, something like this:

```
ID,NAME,TEXT  
01,John,"Lore ipsum.."
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly as asked, however this is what worked best for me:

1. Save the CSV in Excel normally (File > Save As > CSV (Comma separated))
2. Open a powershell window where the exported CSV is
3. Run this command (considering the CSV file was named "Book1.csv":

   import-csv -path .\Book1.csv -Delimiter ";" | export-csv -path .\Book1_comma.csv -Delimiter ","

Comment: This saved me a lot, when I tried to import Backlog Work Items into Azure DevOps.
After import-csv I had to remove the first comment-line otherwise it won't import.

Answer (score 0):

The following Microsoft article details the procedure you're looking for; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291296 In the spirit of SO, I'll summarise here.

In Excel (I'm using 2003), navigate to **Tools** > **Macro** > **Visual Basic Editor**. That will launch the editor in a new window.

Next you want **Insert** > **Module**. In that window, paste the VB code, as follows:

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport()
   ' Dimension all variables.
   Dim DestFile As String
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim ColumnCount As Integer
   Dim RowCount As Integer

   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
      & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")

   ' Obtain next free file handle number.
   FileNum = FreeFile()

   ' Turn error checking off.
   On Error Resume Next

   ' Attempt to open destination file for output.
   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

   ' If an error occurs report it and end.
   If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
      End
   End If

   ' Turn error checking on.
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Loop for each row in selection.
   For RowCount = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count

      ' Loop for each column in selection.
      For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

         ' Write current cell's text to file with quotation marks.
         Print #FileNum, """" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
            ColumnCount).Text & """";

         ' Check if cell is in last column.
         If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
            ' If so, then write a blank line.
            Print #FileNum,
         Else
            ' Otherwise, write a comma.
            Print #FileNum, ",";
         End If
      ' Start next iteration of ColumnCount loop.
      Next ColumnCount
   ' Start next iteration of RowCount loop.
   Next RowCount

   ' Close destination file.
   Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Next you'll need to highlight the cells in your spreadsheet that you want to export. Once they've been selected, **Run** your macro against them. Specify a path to save your file to, and you're done.

Full credits to the author of the article at Microsoft, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291296.

Comment: Any idea how to make the output file "utf8"?